# Unable to run tests with an alias in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm just getting started in Clojure, and I'm trying to figure out how to run tests using an alias. Here's what my `deps.edn` file looks like:

```
 {:paths ["src"]
 :aliases {
           :test {:extra-paths ["test"]
                  :main-opts ["-e" "(require 'clacks/core-test) (clojure.test/run-tests 'clacks/core-test)"]}}}
```

Here's what my directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── deps.edn
├── src
│   └── clacks
│       └── core.clj
└── test
    └── clacks
        └── core_test.clj
```

Here's what my  `core_test.clj` file looks like:

```
(ns clacks.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer [deftest is testing run-test]]
    [clacks.core :refer [alphabet]]))

(deftest alphabet-test 
  (testing "Testing the alphabet"
    (is (map? alphabet) "Not a map!")
    (is (seq alphabet))))
(run-test alphabet-test)
```

And finally, here's the error I'm getting when I try to run `clj -M:test`

> Could not locate core_test__init.class, core_test.clj or
> core_test.cljc on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes
> Blockquote
> use underscores in the Clojure file name.

Any idea why this is happening? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `require 'clacks/core-test` - why is it a `/` there and not a `.`? Same when you use the symbol as the namespace later.

Comment: You should write this as an answer Eugene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace segments are separated with dots, not slashes - regardless of whether it's in some `(ns ...)` form or some other context, like `(require ...)`.

So this part

```
(require 'clacks/core-test) (clojure.test/run-tests 'clacks/core-test)
```

should be

```
(require 'clacks.core-test) (clojure.test/run-tests 'clacks.core-test)
```